# Shader linking fails without error message only on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, c++, shader, opengl-es-2.0, emscripten

I'm working on a graphics engine written in C++. We currently can either build for desktop or for web (using emscripten). Both platforms utilize OpenGL ES 2.0.

I have a vertex and a fragment shader:

## Vertex Shader

```
    #version 100
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
    attribute vec3 a_normal;
    attribute vec3 a_tangent;
    attribute vec3 a_bitangent;

    uniform mat4 u_model;
    uniform mat4 u_view;
    uniform mat4 u_projection;
    uniform mat3 u_normalMatrix;

    varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    varying vec3 v_normal;
    varying vec3 v_fragPos;
    varying mat3 v_TBN;

    void main()
    {
        vec3 T = normalize(vec3(u_model * vec4(a_tangent, 0.0)));
        vec3 B = normalize(vec3(u_model * vec4(a_bitangent, 0.0)));
        vec3 N = normalize(vec3(u_model * vec4(a_normal, 0.0)));
        v_TBN = mat3(T, B, N);

        gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * u_model * a_position;
        v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
        v_normal = u_normalMatrix * a_normal;
        v_fragPos = vec3(u_model * a_position);
    };
```

## Fragment Shader

```
    #version 100
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    varying vec3 v_normal;
    varying vec3 v_fragPos;
    varying mat3 v_TBN;

    struct Material {
        sampler2D diffuse;
        sampler2D specular;
        sampler2D normal;
        float shininess;
    };

    struct Light {
        int type;
        vec3 position;
        vec3 direction;
        vec3 ambient;
        vec3 diffuse;
        vec3 specular;
        float constant;
        float linear;
        float quadratic;
        float cutOff;
        float outerCutOff;
    };

    const int MAX_LIGHTS = 16;

    uniform vec3 u_viewPos;
    uniform Material u_material;
    uniform Light u_lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
    uniform int u_lightCount;
    uniform bool normalMapping;

    vec3 calcDirLight(Light light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);
    vec3 calcPointLight(Light light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);
    vec3 calcSpotLight(Light light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);

    void main()
    {
        vec3 lightOutput = vec3(0.0);
        vec3 norm = normalize(v_normal);
        if (normalMapping)
        {
            norm = texture2D(u_material.normal, v_texcoord).rgb;
            norm = normalize(norm * 2.0 - 1.0);
            norm = normalize(v_TBN * norm);
        }
        vec3 viewDir = normalize(u_viewPos - v_fragPos);

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
        {
            if (i >= u_lightCount){break;}
            if (u_lights[i].type == 0)
            {
                lightOutput += calcDirLight(u_lights[i], norm, viewDir)
            }
            else if (u_lights[i].type == 1)
            {
                lightOutput += calcPointLight(u_lights[i], norm, viewDir);
            }
            else if (u_lights[i].type == 2)
            {
                lightOutput += calcSpotLight(u_lights[i], norm, viewDir);
            }
        }
        
        gl_FragColor = vec4(lightOutput, 1.0);
    }
        
    vec3 calcDirLight(Light light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
    {
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);
        float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), u_material.shininess);
        vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture2D(u_material.diffuse, v_texcoord));
        vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture2D(u_material.diffuse, v_texcoord));
        vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture2D(u_material.specular, v_texcoord));
        return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
    }
        
    vec3 calcPointLight(Light light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
    {
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - v_fragPos);
        float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), u_material.shininess);
        float distance = length(light.position - v_fragPos);
        float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));
        vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture2D(u_material.diffuse, v_texcoord));
        vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture2D(u_material.diffuse, v_texcoord));
        vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture2D(u_material.specular, v_texcoord));
        ambient *= attenuation;
        diffuse *= attenuation;
        specular *= attenuation;
        return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
    }

    vec3 calcSpotLight(Light light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)
    {
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - v_fragPos);
        float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
        vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
        float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), u_material.shininess);
        float distance = length(light.position - v_fragPos);
        float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));
        float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(light.direction));
        float epsilon = light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff;
        float intensity = clamp((theta - light.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0, 1.0);
        vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture2D(u_material.diffuse, v_texcoord));
        vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture2D(u_material.diffuse, v_texcoord));
        vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture2D(u_material.specular, v_texcoord));
        ambient *= attenuation * intensity;
        diffuse *= attenuation * intensity;
        specular *= attenuation * intensity;
        return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
    };
```

They both compile without errors, but the linking stage fails. The info log (accessed using glGetProgramInfoLog) is empty.

The biggest problem is that it compiles and links perfectly fine on desktop native and desktop browsers (emscripten). It only fails linking on mobile devices.

I've spent hours trying to figure this out, without success. Is there anything obvious i might have missed?

Edit 1: This is the code that builds the shader program:

```
    GLuint GLES2Shader::buildProgram(GLuint vertexShader, GLuint fragmentShader)
    {

        GL( GLuint programObject = glCreateProgram() );

        GL( glAttachShader(programObject, vertexShader) );
        GL( glAttachShader(programObject, fragmentShader) );

        GL( glLinkProgram(programObject) );

        //check if the program linked successfully
        GLint linked;
        GL( glGetProgramiv(programObject, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked) );
        if (!linked)
        {
            DEBUG( GLchar infoLog[512] );
            DEBUG( glGetProgramInfoLog(programObject, 512, NULL, infoLog) );
            DEBUG( LOGE("ERROR::SHADER::LINKING_FAILED %s", infoLog) );

            GL( glDeleteProgram(programObject) );
            return 0;
        }
        return programObject;
    }
```

Comment: You should post the linker errors here.

Comment: That's the thing, there are none. Like i said, the program info log is completely empty. I only know that it fails linking, nothing more.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to retrieve the info log -- you've definitely passed a suitably sized buffer to [`glGetProgramInfoLog`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetProgramInfoLog.xml)?

Comment: I put it in the OP. The error message logged by LOGE is just "ERROR::SHADER::LINKING_FAILED", with nothing after that where the error log should be.